# Error in RK4 algorithm in Python

Tags: python, ode

I am solving a nonlinear Schrodinger (NLS) equation:

```
(1): i*u_t + 0.5*u_xx + abs(u)^2 * u = 0
```

after applying Fourier Transform, it becomes:

```
(2): uhat_t = -0.5*i*k^2 * uhat + i * fft(abs(u)^2 * u)
```

where `uhat` is the Fourier Transform of `u`. The equation (2) above is a pretty stated IVP, which can be solved by the 4th oder Runge-Kutta method. Here are my code for solving equation (2):

```
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


#----- Numerical integration of ODE via fixed-step classical Runge-Kutta -----

def RK4(TimeSpan,uhat0,nt):
    h = float(TimeSpan[1]-TimeSpan[0])/nt
    print h 
    t = np.empty(nt+1)
    print np.size(t)        # nt+1 vector
    w = np.empty(t.shape+uhat0.shape,dtype=uhat0.dtype)
    print np.shape(w)       # nt+1 by nx matrix
    t[0]   = TimeSpan[0]    
    w[0,:] = uhat0          # enter initial conditions in w
    for i in range(nt):
        t[i+1]   = t[i]+h   
        w[i+1,:] = RK4Step(t[i], w[i,:],h)
    return w

def RK4Step(t,w,h):
    k1 = h * uhatprime(t,w)
    k2 = h * uhatprime(t+0.5*h, w+0.5*k1*h)
    k3 = h * uhatprime(t+0.5*h, w+0.5*k2*h)
    k4 = h * uhatprime(t+h,     w+k3*h)
    return w + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6.

#----- Constructing the grid and kernel functions -----
L   = 40
nx  = 512
x   = np.linspace(-L/2,L/2, nx+1)
x   = x[:nx]  

kx1 = np.linspace(0,nx/2-1,nx/2)
kx2 = np.linspace(1,nx/2,  nx/2)
kx2 = -1*kx2[::-1]
kx  = (2.* np.pi/L)*np.concatenate((kx1,kx2))

#----- Define RHS -----
def uhatprime(t, uhat):
    u = np.fft.ifft(uhat)
    z = -(1j/2.) * (kx**2) * uhat + 1j * np.fft.fft((abs(u)**2) * u)
    return z

#------ Initial Conditions -----
u0      = 1./np.cosh(x)#+1./np.cosh(x-0.4*L)
uhat0   = np.fft.fft(u0)

#------ Solving for ODE -----
TimeSpan = [0,10.]
nt       = 100
uhatsol  = RK4(TimeSpan,uhat0,nt) 
print np.shape(uhatsol)
print uhatsol[:6,:]
```

I printed out the fist 6 steps of the iteration, the error occurred at the 6th step, I don't  understand why this happened. The results of the 6 steps are:

```
nls.py:44: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  z = -(1j/2.) * (kx**2) * uhat + 1j * np.fft.fft((abs(u)**2) * u)
(101, 512)
[[  4.02123859e+01 +0.00000000e+00j  -3.90186082e+01 +3.16101312e-14j
    3.57681095e+01 -1.43322854e-14j ...,  -3.12522653e+01 +1.18074871e-13j
    3.57681095e+01 -1.20028987e-13j  -3.90186082e+01 +1.62245217e-13j]
 [  4.02073593e+01 +2.01061092e+00j  -3.90137309e+01 -1.95092228e+00j
    3.57636385e+01 +1.78839803e+00j ...,  -3.12483587e+01 -1.56260675e+00j
    3.57636385e+01 +1.78839803e+00j  -3.90137309e+01 -1.95092228e+00j]
 [  4.01015488e+01 +4.02524105e+00j  -3.89110557e+01 -3.90585271e+00j
    3.56695007e+01 +3.58076808e+00j ...,  -3.11660830e+01 -3.12911766e+00j
    3.56695007e+01 +3.58076808e+00j  -3.89110557e+01 -3.90585271e+00j]
 [  3.98941946e+01 +6.03886019e+00j  -3.87098310e+01 -5.85991079e+00j
    3.54849686e+01 +5.37263725e+00j ...,  -3.10047495e+01 -4.69562640e+00j
    3.54849686e+01 +5.37263725e+00j  -3.87098310e+01 -5.85991079e+00j]
 [  3.95847537e+01 +8.04663227e+00j  -3.84095149e+01 -7.80840256e+00j
    3.52095058e+01 +7.15970026e+00j ...,  -3.07638375e+01 -6.25837011e+00j
    3.52095070e+01 +7.15970040e+00j  -3.84095155e+01 -7.80840264e+00j]
 [  1.47696187e+22 -7.55759947e+22j   1.47709575e+22 -7.55843420e+22j
    1.47749677e+22 -7.56093844e+22j ...,   1.47816312e+22 -7.56511230e+22j
    1.47749559e+22 -7.56093867e+22j   1.47709516e+22 -7.55843432e+22j]]
```

At the 6th step, the values of the iteration are crazy.
Aslo, the overflow error occurred here.

Any help?? Thank you!!!!

Comment: In this line: `z = -(1j/2.) * (kx**2) * uhat + 1j * np.fft.fft((abs(u)**2) * u)`, it's different from the function (2) you provided. Is there a '+' or '*' between the uhat and 1j?

Comment: I made a mistake in equation (2), it should be 'uhat_t = -0.5*i*k^2 * uhat + i * fft(abs(u)^2 * u)'. @ Huan-Yu Tseng. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different errors were obvious in the first parsing.

1. (was not an error, `ifft` is indeed the complete inverse of `fft`. This might not be the case in other libraries.)
2. In the RK4 step, you have to decide on one place for the factor `h`. Either (as example, the others analogously)

   ```
    k2 = f(t+0.5*h, y+0.5*h*k1)
   ```

   or

   ```
    k2 = h*f(t+0.5*h, y+0.5*k1)
   ```

---

However, correcting these points only delays the blowup. That there is the possibility for dynamical blow-up is no wonder, it is to be expected from the cubic term. In general one can only expect "slow" exponential growth if all terms are linear or sub-linear.

To avoid "unphysical" singularities, one has to scale the step size inversely proportional to the Lipschitz constant. Since the Lipschitz constant here is of size `u^2`, one has to dynamically adapt. I found that using 1000 steps in the interval [0,1], i.e., `h=0.001`, proceeds without singularity. This still holds true for 10 000 steps on the interval [0,10].

---

**Update** The part of the original equation without the time derivative is self-adjoint, which means that the norm square of the function (integral over the square of the absolute value) is preserved in the exact solution. The general picture is thus a high-dimensional "rotation" (cf. discussions of solid-body kinematics for pattern that evolve already in 3 dimensions).

The problem now is that parts of the function might "rotate" with such a small radius or such a high velocity that a time step represents a large part of a rotation or even multiple rotations. This is hard to capture with numerical methods, which requires thus a reduction in the time step. The general name for this phenomenon is "stiff differential equation": Explicit Runge-Kutta methods are ill-suited for stiff problems.

---

**Update2:** Employing [methods used before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29617089/3088138), one can solve the linear part in the decoupled frequency domain using (note that these are all component-wise array operations)

```
vhat = exp( 0.5j * kx**2 * t) * uhat
```

which allows for a stable solution with larger step sizes. As in the treatment of the KdV equation, the linear part `i*u_t+0.5*u_xx=0` decouples under the DFT to

```
i*uhat_t-0.5*kx**2*uhat=0
```

and can thus be easily solved into the corresponding exponential functions

```
exp( -0.5j * kx**2 * t).
```

The full equation is then tackled using variation of constants by setting

```
uhat = exp( -0.5j * kx**2 * t)*vhat.
```

This lifts some of the burden of the stiffness for the larger components of `kx`, but still, the third power remains. So if the step size gets to large, the numerical solution explodes in very few steps.

Working code below

```python
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


#----- Numerical integration of ODE via fixed-step classical Runge-Kutta -----

def RK4Step(odefunc, t,w,h):
    k1 = odefunc(t,w)
    k2 = odefunc(t+0.5*h, w+0.5*k1*h)
    k3 = odefunc(t+0.5*h, w+0.5*k2*h)
    k4 = odefunc(t+h,     w+k3*h)
    return w + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*(h/6.)

def RK4Stream(odefunc,TimeSpan,uhat0,nt):
    h = float(TimeSpan[1]-TimeSpan[0])/nt
    print(f"step size {h}") 
    w = uhat0
    t = TimeSpan[0]
    while True:
        w = RK4Step(odefunc, t, w, h)
        t = t+h
        yield t,w

#----- Constructing the grid and kernel functions -----
L   = 40
nx  = 512
x, dx = np.linspace(-L/2,L/2, nx+1, retstep=True)
x   = x[:-1]  # periodic boundary, last same as first

kx  = 2*np.pi*np.fft.fftfreq(nx, dx) # angular frequencies for the fft bins

def uhat2vhat(t,uhat):
    return np.exp( 0.5j * (kx**2) *t) * uhat

def vhat2uhat(t,vhat):
    return np.exp(- 0.5j * (kx**2) *t) * vhat

#----- Define RHS -----
def uhatprime(t, uhat):
    u = np.fft.ifft(uhat)
    return - 0.5j * (kx**2) * uhat + 1j * np.fft.fft((abs(u)**2) * u)

def vhatprime(t, vhat):
    u = np.fft.ifft(vhat2uhat(t,vhat))
    return  1j * uhat2vhat(t, np.fft.fft((abs(u)**2) * u) )

#------ Initial Conditions -----
u0      = 1./np.cosh(x) #+ 1./np.cosh(x+0.4*L)+1./np.cosh(x-0.4*L) #symmetric or remove jump at wrap-around
uhat0   = np.fft.fft(u0)

#------ Solving for ODE -----
t0 = 0; tf = 10.0;
TimeSpan = [t0, tf]
# nt       = 500 # limit case, barely stable, visible spurious bumps in phase
nt       = 1000 # boring  but stable. smaller step sizes give same picture
vhat0 = uhat2vhat(t0,uhat0)

fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :]) 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, :])
ax1.set_ylim(-0.2,2.5); ax1.set_ylabel("$u$ amplitude")
ax2.set_ylim(-6.4,6.4); ax2.set_ylabel("$u$ angle"); ax2.set_xlabel("$x$")

line1, = ax1.plot(x,u0)
line2, = ax2.plot(x,u0*0)

vhatstream = RK4Stream(vhatprime,[t0,tf],vhat0,nt)

def animate(i):
    t,vhat = vhatstream.next()
    print(f"time {t}")
    u = np.fft.ifft(vhat2uhat(t,vhat))
    line1.set_ydata(np.real(np.abs(u)))
    angles = np.real(np.angle(u))
    # connect the angles over multiple periods
    offset = 0;
    tau = 2*np.pi
    if angles[0] > 1.5: offset = -tau
    if angles[0] < -1.5: offset = tau
    for i,a in enumerate(angles[:-1]):
        diff_a = a-angles[i+1]
        angles[i] += offset
        if diff_a > 2 : 
            offset += tau
            if offset > 9: offset = tau-offset
        if diff_a < -2 : 
            offset -= tau
            if offset < -9: offset = -tau-offset
    angles[-1] += offset
    line2.set_ydata(angles)
    return line1,line2

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=15000/nt+10, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

One can speed up the animation by computing multiple RK4 steps per frame, increasing the visible step size.

If one wants to use the ODE solvers from `scipy.integrate`, one has to implement some wrappers as these are not hardened against the use of complex-valued data.

```python
# the stepper functions can not handle complex valued data
def RK45Stream(odefunc,TimeSpan,uhat0,nt):
    def odefuncreal(t,ureal):
        u = ureal.reshape([2,-1])
        deriv = odefunc(t,u[0]+1j*u[1])
        return  np.concatenate([deriv.real, deriv.imag])
    t0,tf = TimeSpan
    h = float(tf-t0)/nt
    print("step size ", h) 
    w = np.concatenate([uhat0.real, uhat0.imag])
    t = t0
    stepper = RK45(odefuncreal, t0, w, tf, atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-12)
    out_t = t0
    while True:
        t = t+h
        while t > stepper.t: stepper.step()
        if t>out_t: out_t, sol = stepper.t, stepper.dense_output()
        w = sol(t); w=w.reshape([2,-1])
        yield t,w[0]+1j*w[1]
```

Comment: Thank you @Lutzl!. I misunderstand what you said previously. The time step size is an issue here. As for the `fft(ifft(uhat)) == n*uhat  and  ifft(fft(u))==n*u`, I did noticed this before, however, while I tried this in Python 2.7.6, say: `u = array([0, 1, 2]), fft.ifft(u) = array([ 1.0+0.j        , -0.5-0.28867513j, -0.5+0.28867513j]), fft.fft(fft.ifft(u)) = array([ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  2.+0.j]) =u`. Python gave me `fft(ifft(uhat)) == uhat`, instead of  `fft(ifft(uhat)) == n*uhat`

Comment: Ok, then this follows a different standard. So this point does not stand, increasing the severeness of the step size problem. The usual test for a "good" problem is to integrate the same problem with 3 different step sizes `h, h/2, h/4` and test if the differences at the final time behave according to the error order.

Comment: Thank you @LutzL! Your code is amazing! However, as a beginner, I have some hard time on understanding all of it. I have several more questions about it: (1) **The decoupled frequency domain** means introducing `t` into the RHS of the ODE? Then the **self-ajoint** problem can be avoided? (2) **The flow diagram of the code**, in the function `RK4Stream`, there is a `yield`, which is new to me. I know it returns a generator, but still confused about what it can do here. (3) **line2, = ax2.plot(x,u0*0)**. What does the `u0*0` mean? Many thanks again!!!

Comment: The `yield` generates the solution as a list of state vectors, only that the elements are dynamically generated. It is a standard method for the use of `FuncAnimation`. -- `u0*0` generates a zero-vector of the correct dimension. This is just to initialize the plot window.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Lutzl!!! The code works excellently for pseudo-spectral method, and it is very readable and understandable for me!