# spectral solution to 1D KdV equation

Tags: matlab, ode, pde

I am trying to solve the solution of a 1D KdV equation (ut+uux+uxxx=0) starting from a two solitons initial condition using Fourier spectral method. My code blows up the solution for a reason that I cannot figure out. I would appreciate any help. This is my main code file:

```
%Spatial variable on x direction
L=4; %domain on x
delta=0.05; %spatial step size
xmin=-L; %minimum boundary
xmax=L; %maximum boundary 
N=(xmax-xmin)/delta; %number of spatial points
x=linspace(xmin,xmax,N); %spatial vector

% 1D Initial state
sigma1 = 2; sigma2 = 4;
c1     = 2;     c2 = 1;
h1     = 1;     h2 = 0.3;
U = h1*sech(sigma2*(x+c1)).^2+h2*sech(sigma1*(x-c2)).^2;

%Fast Fourier Transform to the initial condition                 
Ut = fftshift(fft(U));
Ut = reshape(Ut,N,1);
%1D Wave vector disretisation 
k = (2*pi/L)*[0:(N/2-1) (-N/2):-1];  
k(1) = 10^(-6);
k = fftshift(k);
k = reshape(k,N,1);

%first derivative (advection)
duhat = 1i *k .*Ut;
du = real(ifft(ifftshift(duhat))); %inverse of FT
%third derivative (diffusion)
ddduhat = -1i * (k.^3) .*Ut;
dddu = real(ifft(ifftshift(ddduhat))); %inverse of FT

% Time variable
dt = 0.1; %time step
tspan = [0 4];

%solve
Time = 50; 
for TimeIteration = 1:2:Time
t= TimeIteration * dt; 
[Time,Sol] = ode45('FFT_rhs_1D',tspan,U,[],du,dddu);
Sol = Sol(TimeIteration,:);
%plotting
plot(x,abs(Sol),'b','LineWidth',2);
end
```

And this is the function that solves the equation:

```
function rhs = FFT_rhs_1D(tspan,U,dummy,du,dddu)
%solve the right hand side
rhs = - U .* du - dddu;
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop? Does this code even run? (`FFT_rhs_1D` has too many input arguments for `ode45`)

Comment: The loop shows you how the solution changes with time. You can surely remove it but then we need to choose a specific time to see the resulting solution. The function file does not run, it is being called by the main file. The ode45 file has the main inputs; initial condition and the time span, in addition to the two derivatives. All of these inputs are necessary for the right hand side of the kdv equation to be evaluated.

Comment: I am thinking that the reason behind why the code is not giving a stable solution is because of the higher order numerical stiffness, but I don't know what should be done in this situation or what line in the code that needs to be modified/removed!

Comment: @Lama Did you ever resolve this? I also have trouble with blowups, even with just a single soliton.

Comment: The (first?) problem here is that the space derivative are only computed once for the initial state and then kept constant. So essentially you are solving a system of decoupled scalar equations `dU(i)/dt = a(i)*U(i)+b(i)` and convergence depends on the sign of `a(i)=du(i)`. Of course, this solution is completely unrelated to the original PDE. /// Move the Fourier transform into the ODE function. Perhaps even employ operator splitting, that is, apply an integrating factor that combines the linear terms, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617089 for a local discussion.